# If optional.isPresent() then use optional value as method parameter

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have an object containing a couple of optionals, where the optional is not null, I would like to pass its value as a parameter to method that takes more than one parameter.

Currently I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
if (dealerRequest.getIsApproved().isPresent()) {                
    repository.updateDealerPartnerFinanceIsApproved(dealerRequest.getDealerId(), dealerRequest.getIsApproved().get());
}
if (dealerRequest.getIsOptedIn().isPresent()) {                
    repository.updateDealerPartnerFinanceOptedIn(dealerRequest.getDealerId(), dealerRequest.getIsOptedIn().get());
}
```

I know that checking the value is present, and then getting it later is little more use than a null check used to be; however I can't see how else to use them in this case?

Ideally I would .map() the optional to the method on my repository, but then I don't know how to pass (if I can) the 2nd argument? Is there a more succinct way of doing this?

Comment: So if there's no value in your optional, you just don't execute anything on your repositories? Is this correct? Or are you updating your repos with a default value if your optional is null?

Comment: Correct, if the optional has no value, the associated repository update is not called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can as well use `ifPresent()`:

```
dealerRequest.getIsApproved().ifPresent(
  approved -> repository.updateDealerPartnerFinanceIsApproved(dealerRequest.getDealerId(), approved));
```

and correspondingly for the second optional.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) because `map` expects you to return an `Optional`.  You can use [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) ("i**f**" not "i**s**") like so:

```
dealerRequest.getIsApproved().ifPresent(
    retrn -> repository.updateDealerPartnerFinanceIsApproved(foo.getDealerId(), retrn)
);
//(foo = dealerRequest. it overflowed otherwise)
```

[Runnable example](https://ideone.com/fork/E7Hb9Z)

Comment: You don't seem to *actually* use `ifPresent`. Also, the link to your runnable example points to the service's homepage.

Comment: I'm embarrassed. Thanks.